# Is it possible in Azure DevOps Pipelines to wait for enough agents to run the job

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We are running into the following issue:
We have a job in our pipeline that runs tests. The number of tests need to be distributed over 4 agents to run optimal. It can happen that only one agent is available and the job will start to run all the load on that specific agent, which can then time-out because it takes too long for other agents to become available in time to share in the load.

In essence, if we run with 4 agents, the job will run with optimal efficiency.

My question: is it possible to let a job wait for a specific number of agents to become available before starting the tasks in the job?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to wait for the desired number of agents. Technically the 'fastest time' to your results is to start the job as quickly as possible. You can probably create a simple task/step that queries the agent pool and waits for the right number if agents to be available before it continues, but that would still keep one agent busy and potentially time out the job.

Comment: you need to split tests between jobs\stages in your build

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing, I was also thinking in that direction, the waiting would use a different type of agent, and maybe one machine with multiple agents since it would be a simple task anyhow. Coming to think of it, it might run into a race condition with other queued runs, but that would be solved with the waiting agent queue.

I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That`s not possible through out-of-box features.... But you may create a simple PowerShell script that will query your agents statuses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

and use `includeAssignedRequest`

`GET  https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?includeAssignedRequest={includeAssignedRequest}&api-version=7.1-preview.1`

if you see `assignedRequest`, your build agent is busy...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shamrai Alexander, I should have waited for your answer ;) , I was already at this point after an hour of trying out. Good to see I came up with similar code.
I decided to create a pipeline extension to handle this for us